# EF Multiple DbContexts using common base class

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 6.1 code first and have a number of dbcontext models that are in separate library plugins. I also have a common base class model that is also in a separate core library. I am using TPT inheritance.
I would like to know how to code the plugin models so that they do not need to have the common base class table. This what my plugin context looks like right now:

```
public partial class NewsModel : DbContext
{
    public NewsModel()
        : base( "name=NewsModel" )
    {
    }

    public NewsModel( String connectionString )
        : base( connectionString )
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ContentBase> ContentBaseSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<NewsItem> News { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<NewsFeed> NewsFeeds { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
    }
```

I would like to remove ContentBaseSet due to the fact that when issuing an add-migration command, ALL content types ( declared in other plugin libraries and core ) are added to the migration(s). I want the add-migration for NewModel to exclude ContentBase and all other types inheriting from it.
I am sure that there is way to do this by modifying the plugin dbcontext by using DbModelBuilder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom attribute class along with a custom convention to unmap entities that were not wanted in my modular plugin content type libraries (all content types are derived from a ContentBase abstract class ).

Here is the attribute class.

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class )]
public class CoreContentEntity : Attribute
{
}
```

Each core content type has this attribute.

```
[Table("cms_Events")]
[CoreContentEntity]
public partial class Event : ContentBase
{
```

Now for each plugin content type (dbcontext class) add the custom convention.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<UnmapCoreEntitiesConvention>();
    }
```

Finally, here is the custom convention.

```
public class UnmapCoreEntitiesConvention : Convention
{
    public UnmapCoreEntitiesConvention()
    {
        Types()
            .Where( t => t.CustomAttributes.Any( n => n.AttributeType == typeof( CoreContentEntity ) ) )
            .Configure( config => config.Ignore() );
    }
}
```

In order for TPT inheritance to work in the plugin content classes, I still need to include the core ContentBase class in the model dbcontext class. If anyone knows how to get around that I would like to know ( each plugin type has its own table and the ContentBase class must have its own table ).

Comment: It would be nice if EF 6.1 had a configuration option to only include those entities directly referenced in the dbcontext class.